# Function not working correctly when it is used in another program

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a function that displays a tkinter `Tk` object, in which a `Listbox` shows the files with a specific extension in the program's folder.

Here is my (simplified) function :

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Listbox, Variable
from os import getcwd, listdir

def local_file_selection(title:str = '', extension = '.gif') -> str | None:
    file = ''

    def confirm(): # function called when the button confirm is clicked
        nonlocal file
        try:
            file = lbx_files.get(lbx_files.curselection()[0])
            root.destroy()
        except IndexError: print('Please select a file.')

    dir_path  = getcwd() # get the path of the program
    lst_files = []

    for path in listdir(dir_path):
        if path[-len(extension):] == extension: # is it a gif ?
            lst_files.append(path)              # then add it to list of files
 
    root = Tk()
    root.title(title)

    tkv_files = Variable(value=lst_files) # tkv is for tk variable
    lbx_files = Listbox(root, listvariable=tkv_files) # lbx means listbox
    '''
    When I call local_file_selection in the script : 
        tkv_files.get() == "('my_first_and_only_file.gif',)"
        lbx_files.get(0) == 'my_first_and_only_file.gif'

    But when I call this function in another script : 
        tkv_files.get() == "('my_first_and_only_file.gif',)" # as expected
        lbx_files.get(0) == ''                               # I don't know why
    '''
    btn_confirm = Button(root, text='CONFIRM', command=confirm)

    lbx_files.pack()
    btn_confirm.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    return file
```

When I just called it in this script, it perfectly worked, in `lbx_files` I could select `my_first_and_only_file.gif`.

But I imported this function in another script, and `lbx_files.get(0)` was equal to `''` instead of `'my_first_and_only_file.gif'`, so there wasn't any file name in the listbox, it was empty.

Here is the (simplified) script :

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
from file_selection import local_file_selection


class PictureButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get = lambda: None
        super().__init__(text='SELECT PICTURE', command=self.command, *args, **kwargs)

    def command(self):
        sel = local_file_selection()
        self.get = lambda: sel


root = Tk()
root.title('NEW SITE')


def create(): 
    
    alert = Tk()
    alert.title('')
    Label(alert, text=f"Your name is '{entry_username.get()}' \n Your profile picture name is '{button_picture.get()}'").pack()
    alert.mainloop()

label_username = Label(root,text='username :')
label_picture = Label(root,text='profile picture :')

entry_username = Entry(root)
button_picture = PictureButton(root)

button_create = Button(root, text='SIGN UP', command= create)


label_username.grid(row=0, column=0)
label_picture.grid(row=1, column=0)

entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_picture.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_create.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

How did this happen ? I tried to rename `root`, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Your code does not run. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since you haven't posted the complete runnable code, the rest is guesses; Are you creating more than one instance of `Tk()`? That may be a problem. Also, it looks like you are building a dialog; the easier way to do that is to inherit from `simpledialog.Dialog`.

Comment: Your function `local_file_selection` ends with a `root.mainloop()` this should be removed. In your second program you have another `mainloop` reference. If you wish to run both programs then check out the use of `if __name__ == "__main__"` and use them it both programs.

Comment: Check out this question and answer on `__name__ == "__main__"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do